# Firebase Write/Send Data Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Need a little help. I'm new to learning Android and I am having difficult time connecting the test app to a Firebase database.  My issue specifically is the data isn't being sent to the database. The compiles fine with no error, yet no data is  being written tot he database. I've followed other solutions but nothing seems to work. I have all the necessary dependencies in my gradle. Here is the code:

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference myRef;

In my onCreate I have:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef= database.getReference("message");
myRef.push().setValue("test2");
```

Comment: check this out - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: I started there. No dice.  I had to use Firebase reference instead of FirebaseDatabase. Nothing else worked.

Comment: Have tried to attach a complete listener, to see what is wrong?